# Aligning with and without overline

Tags: horizontal-alignment

I was wondering if, by making some changes, `e^x \overline{e^x}` would produce something that actually aligns the exponents horizontally (currently the exponent under overline is a bit lower than the other one). My intuition is that `\phantom` might help, but I'm not sure how to use it with a command that requires an argument. Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think `$e^x \overline{\textstyle e^x}$` will do what you desire.